# returnin jsp with Jersey 2.6

Tags: java, jersey

I'm trying to return a Viewable class using Jersey 2.6.
I've read a lot of examples but nothing seems to work. I just get 404 response, although I can see that request mapping does work. Here the details:

### web.xml

```
 <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <module-name>helloworld-spring</module-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.proj.configuration.JerseyConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

JerseyConfiguration class

```
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    /**
     * Register JAX-RS application components.
     */
    public JerseyConfiguration () {
        register(HomeResource.class);

        register(JspMvcFeature.class);

        // Logging.
        register(LoggingFilter.class);

        // Tracing support.
        property(ServerProperties.TRACING, TracingConfig.ON_DEMAND.name());
    }
}
```

HomeResource class

```
@Path("jersey-hello")
public class HomeResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/myPage")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable getHello() {
        return new Viewable("/myPage.jsp", this);
    }
}
```

I have myPage.jsp in /WEB-INF/jsp folder

I've tried many combinations like put myPage without .jsp and more...nothing seems to be working

here the url I'm calling:

```
http://localhost:8080/jersey-hello/myPage
```

Comment: I am not an expert, neither I am a noob(I just head about jersey and started reading a bit about using it), though am I not suppose to keep my `.jsp/.html` pages alongside `WEB-INF` folder? Instead of keeping these pages inside the same folder.

Comment: Does it help if you refer to the jsp page as 'jsp/myPage.jsp' or '/jsp/myPage.jsp'?

Comment: I've tried all possible ways to refer the names. I gave up and using jersey to generate jsons only for now.

Answer (score 2):

In general if an absolute path to `JSP` file is provided in a resource file (like `"/myPage.jsp"` in `HomeResource.getHello`), then this path is relative to the base path defined by `templateBasePath` in `web.xml` (and in your case it would be as expected in `/WEB-INF/jsp/myPage.jsp`).

I'm on `Weblogic(12.2.1)` right now dealing with `Jersey(2.21.x)/JSP` and the problem that I see is that for some reason `jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath` from `web.xml` does not make it into internal configuration. In fact many of the `<init-param>` properties don't make it.

Alternatively all required properties may be added directly in `ResourceConfig` derived class and then Jersey recognizes these properties:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyResourceConfig() {
        packages("foo.bar");
        register(LoggingFilter.class);
        register(JspMvcFeature.class);
        // it may be also jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath
        property("jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp", "/WEB-INF/jsp");
        // ... more properties as needed ...
    }
}
```

The `web.xml` I end up with was the following:

```
<web-app version="3.0" ...>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```